# Download files to Azure VM

Tags: azure, google-drive-api, local-storage, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04

I have created an Azure VM with Ubuntu 18.04. Since it does not come with any GUI, I am having trouble with sending my local machine files to VM.

I am looking for a method which will not need any GUI instance to download files from my local machine or from google drive or any method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are connecting to the server via SSH, then you might be able to use SFTP - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol.

Comment: I connect via ssh. could you explain SFTP method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux `scp` command is a standard tool to help transfering files or directories from local to remote server, if you are using Linux or Mac or even Windows with Git Bash. Please refer to the blogs below to know how to use it under command line mode.

1. [The ‘SCP’ Command in Linux – The Easiest Way to Copy Securely](https://blog.udemy.com/scp-command-in-linux/)
2. [scp Linux command](https://www.garron.me/en/articles/scp.html)
3. [SCP Command Examples - Linux / Unix Tutorials](https://www.folkstalk.com/2012/07/scp-command-examples-linux-unix.html)

If you just want to use GUI tools, you can try WinSCP for Windows or FileZilla with `sftp` protocol for cross-platform or these answers for the thread of Ask Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/640744/how-can-i-connect-to-a-server-via-scp-in-lubuntu-15/640837#640837.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) then it might be possible to use [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol).

SFTP is an extension of the SSH protocol that, among other things, allows you to upload files without having to run an FTP server.  There are a number of SSH Clients that support SFTP, see - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients#Technical.

I personally use WinSCP or Putty.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Azure file share`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows) to upload files and map to your VM and if you are using any of the FTP method you can use any tool and [`upload files`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/sftp-creation-template/sftp-on-azure/) using the same